# Behaviour of Plot3D with large numbers

Tags: plotting

I have a problem with Plot3D.

At first I thought it was a problem in general, but while creating a minimal example for posting here, it came out to be a problem with large numbers ...i guess.

Let's see:
This was my original code with large numbers:

```
func1[u_, p_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Max[p, 700000], u > 0}, {Max[p, 100000], u < 0}}]
func2[u_, p_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Min[p, 700000], u > 0}, {Min[p, 100000], u < 0}}]

func3[u_, p_] := func2[u, p]/func1[u, p]
```

I tried to plot them

```
Plot3D[func3[u, p], {u, -1, 1}, {p, 100000, 700000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

but the result was an empty plot.

[image]

I thougt it might be because of the zero in the first of these two plots:

```
Plot[func3[u, 350000], {u, -1, 1}]
Plot[func3[.5, p], {p, 100000, 700000}]
```

[image]

But when creating the example for posting here, I reduced the size of the numbers:

```
func1[u_, p_] := Piecewise[{{Max[p, 7], u > 0}, {Max[p, 1], u < 0}}]
func2[u_, p_] := Piecewise[{{Min[p, 7], u > 0}, {Min[p, 1], u < 0}}]

func3[u_, p_] := func2[u, p]/func1[u, p]
```

and the result is

```
Plot3D[func3[u, p], {u, -1, 1}, {p, 1, 7}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

So why does it work with numbers from 1 to 7 and not with numbers from 100 000 to 700 000?

EDIT:

Seems to have problems with Exclusions:

```
Plot3D[func3[u, p], {u, -1, 1}, {p, 100000, 700000}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic]
```

Shows the expected plot. But

```
Plot3D[func3[u, p], {u, -1, 1}, {p, 100000, 700000}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, ExclusionsStyle -> None]
```

Shows nothing and

```
Plot3D[func3[u, p], {u, -1, 1}, {p, 100000, 700000}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, ExclusionsStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
```

[image]

shows the whole plot beeing an exclusion!?

Please compare with the example in the documentation:

```
Plot3D[Im[Sqrt[x + I y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `ListPlot3D[Table[func3[u, p], {p, 100000, 700000, 10000}, {u, -1, 1, 0.1}]]`. It gives your last image (with different coordinates). Therefore, I find it very strange that `Plot3D` doesn't work. However, it works to a certain degree with `Plot3D[func3[u, p], {u, -100000, 100000}, {p, 100000, 700000}]`.

Comment: Looks like a bug with the handling of exclusions. Try with `ExclusionsStyle -> Red` for example.

Comment: For a simpler example: `Plot3D[Sign[u], {u, -1, 1}, {p, -100, 100}, ExclusionsStyle -> Red]`

Comment: @SimonWoods you're right. But ExclusionsStyle -> None does not work. "Automatic" does. But please have a look at "ExclusionsStyle -> Opacity[0.5]". What's happening here? Is everything in the plot an exclusion?

Comment: @Phab I added an answer to the linked duplicate.  The method I used also works on your plot.  I conjecture an explanation as well, although the explanation is far from complete.